# Finding in a list, then assigning to a variable returns null if result already exists in another variable

Tags: java, anylogic

I have two variables and a list I'm finding items to assign to the variables from:

```
var_A = tl_1;

var_B = findFirst(ground.getTargetLines(), n->n.getName().equals("tl_1"));
```

If the find I perform for var_B contains the same result as var_A, I get null. If var_A is empty or contains a different value, then var_B can be assigned the result of the find.

What am I missing please?

Comment: show us code of findFirst() method?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply . . . its just the findFirst() method of the Java 8 Streams API

Comment: So the type of `var_B` is `Optional<T>`?

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:javascript] and [tag:anylogic]?

Comment: @TheHeadRush yes that's correct

Comment: @DavidConrad because I'm using this code in anylogic software, just in case that is part of the issue.

Comment: @DavidConrad also hopefully if there's anylogic users, they may have alternative suggests for transversing TargetLines list

Comment: All right, but this is [tag:java], not [tag:javascript], correct?

Comment: @DavidConrad yes thats correct, sorry didnt notice it had tagged as Javascript, edited.

Answer (score 0):

### The problematic part

The problem here is the behaviour of the `getName()` functions of the AnyLogic types.

I tried for the type TargetLine (inheriting `getName()` from `com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractMarkup`), but also for RectangularShape (inheriting `getName()` from `com.anylogic.engine.presentation.Shape`), and they both behaved the same.

The AnyLogic documentation explains the `getName()` of `Shape` as follows:

> getName(): If the shape is declared as field in a presentable object class (Agent or Experiment), e.g. if it was drawn in the graphical editor, returns the name of the field, otherwise returns the string UNKNOWN_NAME.

The explanation for `TargetLine`'s `getName()` is similar.

### The unexpected behaviour

When you assign the instance of `TargetLine` or `RectangularShape` or instances of other AnyLogic specific classes to an AnyLogic(!) variable (meaning a variable that is graphically defined on the canvas), the result of `getName()` will change from the name that was defined in the graphical editor in the properties of this instance to the name of the variable that it was assigned onto. You can from this moment on not retrieve the originally defined name anymore, as it was changed internally to the variable's name. The instance however still is the same, only the return value of the `getName()` function changed.

Here is an example for the behaviour:
[image: AnyLogic GUI]

```
traceln(rectangle.getName()); //prints "rectangle"
myRectangle = rectangle;      //assign to AnyLogic Variable
traceln(rectangle.getName()); //prints "myRectangle"
```

This explains why your lambda expression (but also a simple loop using the `getName()` function) will not work as expected after you assigned members of the list that you are searching for by their name to an AnyLogic variable.

### Possible Workarounds

- not assigning the objects you are searching for to AnyLogic variables (you can use normal Java variables, that works fine)
- keeping track of the name-instance pairing yourself by storing this information in a Java Map or similar and accessing this ressource when you search for instances by name

### Conclusion

To sum this up, what the AnyLogic documentation SHOULD state would be more like this:

> getName(): If the shape is declared as field in a presentable object class (Agent or Experiment), e.g. if it was drawn in the graphical editor, returns the name of the field, otherwise returns the string UNKNOWN_NAME. If the shape is being assigned to an AnyLogic variable (a variable drawn in the graphical editor), returns the name of this variable instead. Eg. after running the code `myVar = myShape;`, `getName()` will return *myVar* instead of *myShape*.